# Python selenium switching to iframe issue

Tags: python, selenium

Please answer how to switch to new pop window from the existing webpage window

Comment: Please give some example of how you made your attempts. That would be helpful to give the answer.

Comment: issue resolved after few attempts

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your_xpath_for_Iframe")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

You can switch back to the default content

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```